# Parse in data to return a JSON response in SQL Server 2019 for GET requests?

Tags: python, json, sql-server, flask, get

I am trying to parse a string of an array of objects as an input in SQL Server and return a JSON response from a GET request on a Flask localhost server, however it seems the format of the input data isn't correct as I am receiving a 404 in the server response and an "Expecting value: ..." error on the SQL output query.

I have created a simple Flask endpoint which retrieves a JSON response.

```
@app_bp.route("/example", methods=["GET"])
def example() -> Tuple[flask.wrappers.Response, int]:
    try:
        data_out = request.get_data()
        print(data_out)
        data_out = json.loads(data_out)
        print(data_out)
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"Error": f"{e}"}), 404
    else:
        return jsonify(data_out), 200
```

I used the curl library to test out the request in a terminal and retrieved the correct response (200 status code).

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -d '[{"test": 101}]' "http://127.0.0.1:3080/api/v1/app/example"
```

Returned:

```
[
  {
    "test": 101
  }
]
```

And printed:

```
    b'[{"test": 101}]'
    [{"test": 101}]
```

However, doing the same in SQL threw an error and a 404 and doesn`t return anything:

```
DECLARE @json_input AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '[{"test": 101}]';


DECLARE @xmlRequestObject INT = 0
DECLARE @urlGet VARCHAR(8000) = 'http://127.0.0.1:3080/api/v1/app/example'
DECLARE @return INT = 0
DECLARE @contentType VARCHAR(8000) = 'application/json'

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #json_output
CREATE TABLE #json_output ([output] NVARCHAR(MAX))

    --Create the XML request object
EXEC @return = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @xmlRequestObject OUT;
IF @return <> 0 
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Unable to open HTTP connection.', 10, 1);
    RETURN;
END

--Open the connection
EXEC @return = sp_OAMethod @xmlRequestObject, 'OPEN', NULL, 'GET', @urlGet, 'false';

--Set the request headers
EXEC @return = sp_OAMethod @xmlRequestObject, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type','application/json; charset=utf-8'
EXEC @return = sp_OAMethod @xmlRequestObject, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Accept','application/json'

--Send the request
EXEC @return = sp_OAMethod @xmlRequestObject, 'SEND', NULL, @json_input

--Handle the repsonse
INSERT INTO #json_output ([output]) EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @xmlRequestObject, 'responseText'
SELECT * FROM #json_output
EXEC sp_OADestroy @xmlRequestObject
SELECT * FROM #json_output
```

Returns:

```
b''
"GET /api/v1/app/example HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

SQL output:

```
{   "Error": "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" }
```

I tried different formats of what the input may need to be by going through the documentation however, I am still getting the same error.:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Is there a specific format or any missing steps that are required to retrieve a JSON output in the SQL query output?

Comment: I really suggest using some kind of middle ware over using those *ancient* OAMethod objects, or switching to CLR objects.

Comment: Avoid using the sp_OA* methods on SQL Server. They require special error handling and management which you aren't performing. Even when they are managed correctly the objects they invoke are often not thread safe or properly memory managed, compromising the stability and reliability of SQL Server. If you need to access APIs this is better done in external processes that dequeue requests from SQL Server and return the results to SQL Server.

Comment: Aside... GET requests don't have payloads so they don't have a Content-Type header either. You should probably be using POST if you wish to send data.

Comment: The intention is not to update the server, but rather send the data, perform on the data, and return new data. should this not be a GET request? @AlwaysLearning

Comment: You should probably have a read through [HTTP request methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) and [RFC 9110 9.3.1. GET](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc9110.html#GET). While it's technically possible to send payloads with GET requests it's semantically wrong to do so and you may experience problems with intermediate infrastructure that doesn't expect such behavior.